# filter column with (lookup which can be filtered too)

Tags: filter, data-tables

I have a complicated filter system on the app I worked on where you can filter table columns but the main point is that business requirements ask to filter some columns with lookups. the lookups seem like tables with the ability to filter too. my question is what is the best practice to handle this case?

[image]